# 'u0022' to introduce quotation marks to string C#

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0

I have a string property that returns a directory, it has "program file//" in it, so to use it in a command prompt, I have to use quotation mark around the string. But if I do the following

```
string myDic = someDic;

string myCmdPrptDic = '\u0022' + someDic + "\u0022'
```

myCmdPrptDic ends up like \"C://Program Files//myApp\" and will not work under cmd prompt. Is there a way to just create "C://Program Files//myApp" only? Or maybe I should just use a stringBuilder....

I just need to generate a string like:

```
copy //data/file// "C://program files//myapp"
```

but I could not do it as

```
string = "copy //data//file" +" "+ '\u0022' + someDic + "\u0022';
```

Comment: I assume you mean '\u0022' + someDic  + '\u0022'... Are you looking at the string in the debugger?

Comment: yes, it is shown as "\"C://Program files//myApp\"" when I move my cursor to the string in the debugger.... and the same thing when 2 strings are appended together.

Comment: Please delete the quesiton! It is not the string's problem. It is the problem of an _executeCommand method. I passed exactly same string, one as the exact string, the other as a string with value and the method execute only one of them... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that is actually what your string is and not just the way you are viewing it? In the watch window of VS debugger it puts strings in double quotes already which means it needs to escape any quotes inside it. As it stands the above code will not put the `\` into your string. If it really is in there (and not just a misreading of the debug information) then there is some other code somewhere adding it in.

Comment: How would I know what is the real value then?

Comment: Well, I've described how visual studio displays strings in the watch/locals window (escaping quotes. If you click on the magnifying glass next to it (in the watch/locals or when you hover over the variable when you have stopped at a break point) then you will see the "text visualiser" which will give the "real" view of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes " and ' are mis-matched.